# Consulting agreement vs sales representative agreement

Tags: united-states, contract-law

Can you tell me if there's a difference between "consulting agreement" and "sales representative agreement"? I've been asked to do a research on that but I don't know very much about the topic.

Can you point me in the direction of some paper on the topic/applicable laws?

The company is based in the USA and should market and sell products to an European end user. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me if there's a difference between "consulting agreement"
>   and "sales representative agreement"?

Based solely on the plain meaning of words, *consulting* typically involves more functions than (or functions other than) contacting entities to offer a product or service. However, for purposes of contract law, labels mean very little and are not decisive in a controversy. See [*Howard Trucking Co., Inc. v. Stassi*, 474 So.2d 955 (1985)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/19851429474so2d95511303):

> It is well-established that we are not bound by the label placed on a
>   written agreement or the subjective intent of the contracting parties,
>   but must look to the substance of the transaction in determining
>   rights and obligations. [...] Words will have import and can be
>   binding only when they describe relationships which actually exist,
>   but not when they are merely labels which are used to alter or
>   disguise actual relationships.

Similarly, [*Steiner v. Thexton*, 48 Cal.4th 411, 418 (2010)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/incaco20100318075):

> although the agreement was titled "REAL ESTATE PURCHASE CONTRACT," the
>   label is not dispositive. Rather, we look through the agreement's form
>   to its substance.